# Hiding multiple horizontal rows in the attribute table in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, features, filter

I would like to see only the first 10 of my 150 attributes show up in the attribute table and have the rest 140 attributes "hidden". Is this possible? However, it would have to be possible to have the remaining 140 attributes shown again quickly and easily.

I've figured out how to hide the vertical rows but I couldn't figure out how to hide the horizontal rows.

Comment: You mention that you would like to only see 10 of the 150 attributes, but you would like to hide the horizontal rows. Do you mean you would only like to see the first 10 of your horizontal rows, but you have figured out how to hide vertical columns?

Answer (score 2):

Right Click in the attribute table and select organzie columns
[image: Organzie Columns]

Then uncheck all the columns you do not want to see.

[image: uncheck]

Comment: Or click on the Organize Columns icon (blue and white table with a red pen, 5th from the right).

Answer (score 1):

To hide horizontal lines (rows) follow these steps:

1. Left click on the layer in the table of content and open attribute table with <kbd>F6</kbd>.
2. Select rows you would like to show.
3. Left click on the layer in the table of content (again) and push <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>F6</kbd>

To show all rows again, click `Show All Features` on the menu in the left corner of the attribute table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, would be to create a new attribute field, in which you could label values for only the 10 objects you wish to view as the same value. Then you can sort the rows by that value by clicking on the top of the column you've just created. You could also filter the attribute table by the value you've added to the new field.